# How are the three callback functions received into subscribe method as one object?

Tags: angular, rxjs

After we make some observable

```
let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      let x = 5;
      if (x == 15) {
        observer.error('something went wrong');
      } else {
        observer.next('produce some value');
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
```

there are different ways of subscribing to that three callbacks functions from the observer.

```
observable.subscribe(
      function next(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      function error(err) {
        console.log(err);
      },
      function complete() {
        console.log('done');
      }
    )
```

or with arrow functions istead with function keyword

```
observable.subscribe(
      x => 
      {
      console.log(x);
      },
      err => 
      {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => 
      {
        console.log('done');
      },
```

and this two ways are working - so at the end at the subscribe methods we are ending with three
functions that are getting the values from the observer.

But when i write for example

```
observable.subscribe({
      next: (data) => console.log(data),
      error: (err) => console.log(err),
      complete: () => console.log('done')
    })
```

it is still working. But i dont get it how it is working because here we are having three functions
inside one object. On the previous two examples we had directly three functions.

My question is how and why it is working when the functions are 'wrapped' in one object ?

Comment: That's just how the subscribe method is written. it accepts eather up to 3 callbacks or an object implemented like you did. Both method are equivalent.

Comment: Okay quentin,thanks for your feedback.How can i see the implementation in the background of the subscribe method ?

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable

Comment: you usually can check the type definition in your node_modules. In my case, it's in node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts, then search for "subscribe". But if you want to check for the source code, go check the github repository https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pseudocode implementation of subscribe

```
subscribe(...args){
  let observer = {
    next: _ => {/* Do nothing */},
    error: err => { throw err },
    complete: () => {/* Do nothing */}
  }

  if(isAFunction(args[0])) observer.next = args[0];
  if(isAFunction(args[1])) observer.error = args[1];
  if(isAFunction(args[2])) observer.complete = args[2];

  if(isAnObject(args[0])){
    const partialObserver = args[0];
    if(isAFunction(partialObserver.next)) observer.next = partialObserver.next;
    if(isAFunction(partialObserver.error)) observer.error = partialObserver.error;
    if(isAFunction(partialObserver.complete)) observer.complete = partialObserver.complete;
  }

  return this._subWithObserver(observer);
}
```

Clearly, that's not the full story, but it's an idea toward how it is done. You can dig into the source to see how partial observers and/or functions are mapped into proper observers.

Behinds the scenes, `error` and `complete` are actually instrumented to ensure the Observable contract is upheld.

Comment: Thanks Mrk.I accepted and upvoted your answer. Can you just please write me in the comment or in your answer also the link from the this source code that you pasted here, from their documentation ? I tried to find that here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts but i didn't found it.